# Check if a variable is not empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable called `new_date`.  I am reading dates into this variable but sometimes there is no date read in (the date does not exist).  I want to check if the variable `new_date` is empty and do something different if there is no date in the variable.

For example, I have the code below which first checks if `picked` is less than `prev_final` and `new_date` is a date.

```
if (picked < prev_final) & isinstance(new_date, pd.datetime) 
    # add the value from NEW_DATE
    list_final.append(new_date) 

    # and update the prev_final for the next iteration of the loop
    prev_final = new_date 

# same idea if conditions not met
else:
    list_final.append(picked)
    prev_final = picked
```

To this first line, I would like to add a condition that `new_date` also must have a date (not empty). If its empty I'd like the code to use the `else` i.e. if `new_date` is empty I would like the code to drop down to where I append `picked` to the `list_final` and `prev_final` and not append `new_date`).

For example:

```
if (picked < prev_final) & isinstance(new_date, pd.datetime) & (new_date isnot empty):
```

But I just need to know how to check if `new_date` is empty.

Comment: an empty string has a boolean value of `False` (try `bool('')`). As a result, you can just do `if not new_date:`

Comment: Do you mean `&`?  That is used to set bit patterns.  Maybe you mean `and` instead?

Comment: *Empty* is a vague term. I could imagine, that what you are searching for is *was never assigned any value*. I would simply try to refer the variable and handle the `NameError`exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following selection statement:

```
if (picked < prev_final) and isinstance(new_date, pd.datetime) and (new_date is not None)
```

Answer (score 2):

To check falsy value in python you can do:

```
if not new_date:
    pass
```

also `[]`, `{}`, `0`, `''`, `False`, `None` (and more) will be consider "empty".

Also, watch your possible typo (`&` instead of `and`) as commented by [cdarke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173116/check-is-a-variable-is-not-empty/53173217#comment93236233_53173116)

Comment: you forgot the empty tuple `()`. +1

Comment: also set, decimal, bytes :)

Comment: also `bytearray()` :-)